# Magento2 - How to know in model billing-step or shipping-step

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

Magento2 - I want to know, its billing address or shipping address in checkout page.

How to check, checkout form is billing form or shipping form...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain it via screen short ?

Comment: I want to know in checkout page its billing address form or shipping address form ....that it. via model.php

Comment: This Link Refers to Checkout Customization according to your need: [Click Here](https://inviqa.com/blog/technical-guide-magento-2-checkout) And Also If you want to Manipulate Checkout Form, then this is Reference Document : [Link One](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html) & [Link Two](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_custom_checkbox.html) **With the help of this you can easily, complete your work on Checkout.**

Comment: which type of modification ?